# c# - List Object Element Rollover

Tags: c#, list

I am working on a program that utilizes a List object overloaded to a struct I created.

This program is constantly increasing the size of the List over time indefinitely. I am looking for an algorithm that will be triggered when the size of the List is 50, eliminate the first 25 elements, and move the latter 25 down to the former half, and begin adding elements at the 26th element spot.

Assume entries and testEntries are defined above and templated to a struct i created.

```
if(entries.Count >= 50)
{
    testEntries = entries;
    int x = 0;
    for (x = 0; x < (entries.Count / 2); x++)
    {
        testEntries.RemoveAt(x);
    }
    for (x = 0; x < (entries.Count); x++)
    {
        testEntries.Add(entries[entries.Count / 2]);
    }
entries = testEntries;
}
```

//entries is my original list, testEntries is my second list to help with operations.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: It sounds like what you really want is a `Queue`.

Answer (score 2):

The default implementation of List (any [IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx) in the framework)*, keeps the items with contiguous indexes. That is, that once you remove an item, all the items on the list that are after it will move one position back. To be clear, if you have:

```
 0 -> A
 1 -> B
 2 -> C
 3 -> D
```

If you remove `B` then `C` and `D` will move one space back:

```
 0 -> A
 1 -> C
 2 -> D
```

*: Are you using a custom implementation of List?

---

### Assuming you don't use a custom List

Knwoing that, and since, you are removing at the start of the list, you can just remove at the first position the required amount of items:

```
if(entries.Count >= 50)
{
    testEntries = entries;
    int x = 0;
    for (x = 0; x < (entries.Count / 2); x++)
    {
        testEntries.RemoveAt(0); // <--- Always removing the first item
    }
    //No need
    /*for (x = 0; x < (entries.Count); x++)
    {
        testEntries.Add(entries[entries.Count / 2]);
    }*/
    entries = testEntries;
}
```

You may also want to consider if you want to remove the first half, the first 25 items or until there are only 25 items left. The code above removes the first half.

To remove the first 25, change `for (x = 0; x < (entries.Count / 2); x++)` with `for (x = 0; x < 25; x++)`. To remove until there are 25 items left, I recommend a while:

```
if(entries.Count >= 50)
{
    testEntries = entries;
    while (entries.Count > 25)
    {
        testEntries.RemoveAt(0);
    }
    entries = testEntries;
}
```

---

### Assuming you use a custom List

If you have a custom List that doesn't keep contiguous indexes... You can start by copying the second half on to the first half. Afterwards you can remove the second half.

```
if(entries.Count >= 50)
{
    testEntries = entries;
    int x = 0;
    int pivot = (entries.Count / 2);
    //Copy
    for (x = pivot; x < entries.Count; x++)
    {
        testEntries[x - pivot] = testEntries[x];
    }
    //Remove
    for (x = pivot; x < entries.Count; x++)
    {
        testEntries.RemoveAt(x);
    }
    entries = testEntries;
}
```

---

### Final Note

None of these is thread-safe. If you have multiple threads accessing your object simultaneously, it may result in unexpected results. You should consider using some form of synchronization. I think It is possible to create a lock-free solution, and that is beyond the scope of this post.

Comment: +1 I didnt bothered to read the question but your detailed answer clears everything

Comment: Theraot, I just tried the algorithms out and I believe you are correct on the thread safeness. basically this list is being displayed to a list view object in visual c, and is used by multiple classes on different threads.

After i add 50 items to the list view, it stops adding items and does nothing until i use entries.Clear();

Comment: @DrakeAS I'm not sure what may cause that, but I can tell you this: List<T> uses internally an array, and that array will be copied to a bigger as the number of elements approaches it's maximum capacity... and copying that array is not implemented on a thread-safe way. So, I think you should look for another data-structure, one designed for concurrent operations. Otherwise start using lock(object) everywhere.